# How to set custom checkout payment fields from custom WooCommerce Payment gateway

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, custom-fields

I created the plugins and added custom fields on the checkout page like payment_mode & transaction id.

```
public function process_payment( $order_id ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    
    
    $order->update_status($this->order_status, __( 'Awaiting payment', 'payment' ));
    
    
    wc_reduce_stock_levels( $order_id );
    
    $wcorder = wc_get_order($order_id);
    
    
        $payment_mode     = $_POST['payment_mode'];
        $transaction     = $_POST['transaction'];
        
        if( isset($transaction) && isset($payment_mode) ) {
            
            $wcorder->add_meta_data( 'payment_mode', $payment_mode );
            $wcorder->add_meta_data( 'transaction_id', $transaction );
            $wcorder->save();
        }
}
```

Here the payment mode & transaction is custom filed, It gets the data from users and adds the database table.
In the above coding, $order->update_status - Its working fine. But $wcorder->add_meta_data is not working. It does not show any error and the data is not added to the table.

Comment: You should add all your payment gateway and related code to a Github Gist adding the link in your question, as your code is not testable. Remember that *"your question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem**"*.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `add_meta_data` with `update_meta_data`.

Alternatively you can try with:

```
update_post_meta( $order_id, 'payment_mode', $payment_mode );
update_post_meta( $order_id, 'transaction_id', $transaction );
```

instead of:

```
$wcorder->add_meta_data( 'payment_mode', $payment_mode );
$wcorder->add_meta_data( 'transaction_id', $transaction );
```